# Ansible how naming of file issues

Tags: ansible

I have ansible creating files from the inventory file based off their IPs.

```
  - local_action: file dest=/file{{ groups['firewall'] }}.txt  state=touch
```

When it creates the file however it names it

> [u'10.12.89.12'].txt

Is there a way to get it to name it **10.13.89.12.txt**?

Comment: `{{ groups['firewall'] }}` returns an array, which explains the brackets. Does `{{ groups['firewall'][0] }}` work for you?

Comment: Even though this works now, in my experience relying too much on indices like that might lead to unwanted errors later on. If it is possible it might be better to convert your variable list inside that dictionary to a single value. In that case you don't have to reference the address through an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
- local_action: 
    module: file
    dest: /file/{{ item }}.txt  
    state: touch
  with_items: groups['firewall']
```